# Doctrine ordering toMany associations and matching Criteria

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've an entity with a OneToMany association. In this association I've defined an orderby and It works fine when I retrieve it.

```
class client {
    ...
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reservation", mappedBy="client")
    * @ORM\OrderBy({"reservation_date" = "DESC"})
    */
    protected $reservations;

    ....

    public function getReservations()
    {
        return $this->reservations;
    }

    ....
}
```

The `getReservations` method works fine and It retrieve all `Reservations` ordered by the `reservation_date` field. But if I add this method:

```
public function getActiveReservations() {
    $activeCriteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true));

    return $this->getReservations()->matching($activeCriteria);
}
```

The matching criteria *mess* all results and are not ordered by the `reservation_field`.

How can I preserve the order after a matching criteria?

Comment: You probably need to *reorder* using `Criteria::orderBy`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, if I add `->orderBy(array("reservation_date" => Criteria::DESC))` to the Criteria definition, I get the result ordered. But, why does it not preserve the order?

Comment: I guess that's a side-effect of how `matching` handles the "filtering". If you check the source, you'll see that it goes through quite a lot of code, and probably somewhere the initial ordering is lost.

Answer (score 15):

As said in comments, you can use the `Criteria::orderBy(array $orderings)`

```
$activeCriteria = Criteria::create()
    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("active", true))
    ->orderBy(array('reservation_date' => Criteria::DESC));
```

Don't hesitate to read doctrine's source code if you can't find the answer in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).